# Проблема с FXMLLoader

Tags: javafx, fxml

У меня проблемы с загрузкой fxml файла. Ошибка вылетает когда пытаюсь вывести модальное окно по нажатию кнопки. Делал по примеру главного класса который работает исправно. Вот работающий класс который был сгенерирован автоматически:

public class Main extends Application {

```
 private static Stage prStage;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/Main.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Deck storage");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 429, 517));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    prStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static Stage getPrStage() {
    return prStage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

А вот в этом классе вылетает ошибка:

public class Controller {

```
ObservableList<Deck> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


@FXML
private TableView<Deck> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Deck, String> columnName;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Deck, String> columnClass;

@FXML
private Label label;

String name ="";
String hero ="";
String data ="";

Stage addMenu;

int id = 0;


@FXML
public void initialize(){


    columnName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Deck, String>("name"));
    columnClass.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Deck, String>("hero"));

    list.add(new Deck("","","",0));


}

public void addFromBuffer(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    showAutoDialog();
}

public void addManually(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    showManDialog();
}

public void deleteDeck(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

}

public void deleteAllDecks(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    list.removeAll();
    update();
}

public void showAutoDialog(){
    try {
        addMenu = new Stage();
        Parent rootAddMenu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/EditMenuAuto.fxml"));//Вылетает именно здесь
        addMenu.setTitle("Input data");
        addMenu.setMinHeight(138);
        addMenu.setMinWidth(336);
        addMenu.setResizable(false);
        addMenu.setScene(new Scene(rootAddMenu));
        addMenu.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        addMenu.initOwner(Main.getPrStage());
        addMenu.showAndWait();
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void showManDialog(){
    try {
        addMenu = new Stage();
        Parent rootAddMenu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/EditMenuMan.fxml"));//а так же здесь
        addMenu.setTitle("Input data");
        addMenu.setMinHeight(172);
        addMenu.setMinWidth(336);
        addMenu.setResizable(false);
        addMenu.setScene(new Scene(rootAddMenu));
        addMenu.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        addMenu.initOwner(Main.getPrStage());
        addMenu.showAndWait();
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void update(){
    table.setItems(list);
    label.setText("Number of records: " + String.valueOf(list.size()));
    DataBaseArchiver.writeData(list);
}
```

}

В обоих случаях я одинаково прописал
тут есть ошибка:
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/EditMenuMan.fxml"));
а вот тут нет:
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/Main.fxml"));

Вот сама ошибка:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку или расскажите как правильно создавать и выводить модальное окно по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: класс Controller в каком пакете лежит? Есть подозрение, что не в том же что и Main, поэтому по пути fxml/EditMenuMan.fxml (относительно Controller) файл и не найден.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка "Location is required" при вызове `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/EditMenuMan.fxml"))` возникает из-за того, что `getClass().getResource("fxml/EditMenuMan.fxml")` возвращает `null`, то есть файла по этому пути не находит.

Предположу, что сейчас Ваши файлы в проекте расположены так:

```
src/
    Main.java
    fxml/
         Main.fxml
         Controller.java
         EditMenuAuto.fxml
         EditMenuMan.fxml
```

Поскольку загрузка файла вызывается из `Controller`, а путь `"fxml/EditMenuMan.fxml"` - относительный, то загрузчик пытается найти файл `fxml/fxml/EditMenuMan.fxml`, которого и не находит.

Здесь, как минимум, два решения:

Либо переместить `Controller.java` в ту же папку, что и `Main.java` (и подправить значение атрибута `fx:controller` в `Main.fxml`).

Либо убрать `fxml/` из пути к файлам при загрузке из контроллера:

```
Parent rootAddMenu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EditMenuAuto.fxml"));
...
Parent rootAddMenu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EditMenuMan.fxml"));
```